# Как спарсить от слова до слова) Python

Tags: python, парсер

имею например текст "Now we add a timeout, say an hour, or 90 seconds, or whatever. What happens when the first password"

хочу спарсить от ", or" до "seconds,"
и получить в ответе "90".

НЕ используя регулярок ...

Comment: Если не использовать регулярок, то можно просто взять номера символов в строке и получить их, если они известны, конечно

Answer (score 4):

> НЕ используя регулярок ...

```
text = "Now we add a timeout, say an hour, or 90 seconds, or whatever. What happens when the first password"

start = text.find(', or') + len(', or')
end = text.find(' seconds')
print(text[start: end])
#  90
```

---

**PS.**

Не знаю почему нельзя регулярки, они ведь упрощают:

```
import re

m = re.search(r', or (\d+) seconds', text)
print(m.group(1))
# 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Приведу свое видение parser'а. Но перед тем отмечу, что мой пример излишне сложен под такую простую задачу, и привожу я его только в ознакомительных целях.

```
# 397d19a3c2cf42559d5e877bd89a0417.py

class TBase:
    """
    TBase - базовый класс токена.

    Некоторые методы базового класса
    должны быть переопределены. А
    именно does_it и express. Они
    будут именно методами класса
    (@classmethod).
    """

    '''
    Lexer должен иметь доступ ко всем
    классам, унаследованным от TBase.
    Для этого коллекционируем их в instances.
    '''
    instances = list()

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        TBase.instances.append(cls)
        return cls

    def __str__(self):
        value = '' if self.value == None\
            else f"({self.value})"
        return f"{self.Type}{value}"


    @property
    def Type(self):
        return self.__class__.__qualname__


    @classmethod
    def does_it(self, lexer):
        """
        Возвращает true, если на текущем этапе
        токен может определиться из lexer'а.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "Method should be overridden.")

    @classmethod
    def express(self, lexer):
        """
        Возвращает экземпляр токена, значение
        которого получено разбором lexer'а.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "Method should be overridden.")

class TWhitespaces(TBase):
    
    @classmethod
    def does_it(cls, lexer):
        return lexer.current_char.isspace()

    @classmethod
    def express(cls, lexer):
        while    lexer.current_char != None and\
                lexer.current_char.isspace():
            lexer.advance()
        return cls()

class TWord(TBase):

    @classmethod
    def does_it(cls, lexer):
        return lexer.current_char.isalpha()

    @classmethod
    def express(cls, lexer):
        value = str()
        while    lexer.current_char != None and\
                lexer.current_char.isalpha():
            value += lexer.Eat()
        return cls(value)

class TSpecialChar(TBase):

    CHARS = \
    list(".,?!-")

    @classmethod
    def does_it(cls, lexer):
        return lexer.current_char in\
            TSpecialChar.CHARS

    @classmethod
    def express(cls, lexer):
        value = str()
        while lexer.current_char in TSpecialChar.CHARS:
            value += lexer.Eat()
        return cls(value)

class TInt(TBase):

    @classmethod
    def does_it(cls, lexer):
        return lexer.current_char.isdigit()

    @classmethod
    def express(cls, lexer):
        value = str()
        while    lexer.current_char != None and\
                lexer.current_char.isdigit():
            value += lexer.Eat()
        value = int(value)
        return cls(value)

class Lexer:
    """
    Синтаксически разбирает строковые
    данные на объявленные токены в
    приоритете их объявления
    (расположения в TBase.instances).
    """
    def __init__(self, data):

        self.data = data
        self.tokens = list()
        self.current_pos = -1
        self.current_char = None
        """
        Инициализируем переменные current_*
        и разбираем data на токены.        
        """
        self.advance()
        self.express()

    def advance(self, adjust: int=1):
        """
        Продвигается в self.data на adjust
        символов.

        Текущий символ считается None при
        достижении конца.
        """
        self.current_pos += adjust

        self.current_char = self.data[self.current_pos]\
            if self.current_pos < len(self.data) else None

    def Eat(self, *args):
        """
        Возвращает текущий символ;
        вызывает advance с переданными
        аргументами.
        """
        retr = self.current_char
        self.advance(*args)
        return retr

    def traceback(self):
        """
        Возвращает отрывок с последней
        пройденной частью.
        """
        begin = max(0, self.current_pos - 12)
        end = min(len(self.data),
            self.current_pos + 1)
        excerpt = self.data[begin:end]

        return excerpt + '<'

    def express(self):
        """
        Выполняет синтаксический разбор
        собственных данных на токены.
        """
        while self.current_char != None:
            success = False
            for instance in TBase.instances:
                if instance.does_it(self):
                    token = instance.express(self)
                    self.tokens.append(token)
                    success = True
                    break
            if not success:
                raise SyntaxError(
                    "Unknown syntax.\n\t" +\
                    self.traceback())

def BetweenWords(
    data,
    begin_word,
    end_word,
    with_whitespaces=False):
    """
    Возвращает токены, которые находятся между
    TWord(begin_word) и TWord(end_word).

    Если был встречен begin_word, но до
    конца отсутствовал end_word, то его
    отстуствие будет проигнорировано.
    """
    retr = list()
    now_in = False
    for token in Lexer(data).tokens:
        if now_in:
            if token.Type == "TWord":
                if token.value == end_word:
                    now_in = False
                    break
            if not with_whitespaces:
                if token.Type == "TWhitespaces":
                    continue
            retr.append(token)
        else:
            if token.Type == "TWord":
                if token.value == begin_word:
                    now_in = True
    return retr


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = "Now we add a timeout, say an hour, or 90 seconds, or whatever. What happens when the first password"

    # Информация о всех токенах:
    # print(', '.join([str(token) for token in Lexer(text).tokens]))

    tokens = BetweenWords(
        text, "or", "seconds")
    for token in tokens:
        print(token)
    print('-' * 10)

    result = str(tokens[0].value)
    print(result)
```